# How to deploy asp.net core 2.1 preview app to azure?? how do i install the new sdk in azure

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure-web-app-service

I upgraded to .NET Core 2.1 Preview 1 SDK and I installed the asp.net core 2.1 preview site extension by following the instruction on the below link

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview1-using-asp-net-core-previews-on-azure-app-service/

Expected behavior
expect the newly released sdk to be installed for azure web app

Actual behavior
running dotnet --info on the web app console screen gives the below result:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot

dotnet --info
D:\home\site\wwwroot
.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.4)

Product Information:
Version: 2.1.4
Commit SHA-1 hash: 5e8add2

Runtime Environment:
OS Name: Windows
OS Version: 10.0.14393
OS Platform: Windows
RID: win10-x86
Base Path: D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
Version : 2.0.5
Build : 17373eb129b3b05aa18ece963f8795d65ef8ea54
```

anyone knows how to deploy my asp.net core 2.1 preview app to azure?

Comment: By following the instructions in that link. `If you see ProgramFiles instead then try restarting your site and running the info command again.` Please format the question too, it's unreadable right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you run `dotnet --info`, you should check that the extension is indeed installed:
[image]
You can either go through the linked instruction again or follow my approach:

1. go to your [scm site](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service): `https://<yourWebSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/SiteExtensions#gallery`
2. install dotnet core runtime siteextensions
   [image]
3. verify that it is installed and restart the site
   [image]

Comment: i have successfully deployed the site following the above steps. thank you